# Connecting to azure flexible postgres server via node pg

Tags: node.js, postgresql, azure, azure-sql-database, portforwarding

I am using the free subscription at Azure and have successfully created a Ubuntu Server and a Flexible Postgres Database.

Until recently I accessed the DB directly from my Windows 10 desktop. Now I want to route all access through the Ubuntu Server.

For this I have installed Open SSH Client and Open SSH Server on my Windows 10 machine and done the necessary local port forwarding with `ssh -L 12345:[DB IP]:5432 my_user@[Ubuntu IP]`

The connection works, I confirmed it with pgcli on my desktop with `pgcli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 12345 -u my_user -d my_db`

But when I am trying to connect via node-pg I receive the following error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[Ubuntu IP]", user "my_user", database "my_db", SSL off
```

I have already added a Firewall Rule in Azure with the [Ubuntu IP], and the error remains. What bugs me further is that in the Azure Portal of the DB I have enabled "Allow public access from any Azure service within Azure to this server", so the extra Firewall should not even be necessary for this connection.

For the last week, I have been stuck on this and now the connection is finally established, but not accessible by my code. Pretty frustrating. I would be glad about ANY pointers on how to fix this.

Edit #1:

I can't post the pg_hba.conf file. Because the Postgres DB is managed by Azure, I do not have access to pg_hba, which makes the situation more difficult to understand.

My node.js code for testing the connection:

```
const pg = require("pg");
const passwd = "...";

const client = new pg.Client({
    user: 'admin',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'test',
    password: passwd,
    port: 12345
});
client.connect()

client.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
});

const query = "SELECT * FROM test";
try {client.query(query, (err,res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(res);
})}
catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
}
```

Comment: The azure server pg_hba insists on using ssl, while node insists on *not* using ssl.  Someone has to yield to the other.  You haven't shown either the client's node connection code nor the server's pg_hba, but at looks like one of them needs to change.

Comment: Thank you jjanes, this helped me immensely in understanding what's going on. I'll edit the question concerning pg_hba and my node code and then post the solution I found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by @jjanes helped me in understanding the issue, thank you.

This edited pg.Client config solved my problem:

```
const client = new pg.Client({
    user: 'admin',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    database: 'test',
    password: passwd,
    port: 12345,
    ssl: {rejectUnauthorized: false}
});
```

I found this specific SSL option here https://node-postgres.com/features/ssl